# Match Only Full Paths in Neo4J with Cypher (not sub-paths)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have a graph like the following (where the nesting could go on for an arbitrary number of nodes):

```
(a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)-[:KNOWS]->(c)-[:KNOWS]->(d)-[:KNOWS]->(e)
               |             |
               |            (i)-[:KNOWS]->(j)
               |
              (f)-[:KNOWS]->(g)-[:KNOWS]->(h)-[:KNOWS]->(n)
                             |
                            (k)-[:KNOWS]->(l)-[:KNOWS]->(m)
```

How can I retrieve all of the full-length paths (in this case, from `(a)-->(m)`, `(a)-->(n)` `(a)-->(j)` and `(a)-->(e)`? The query should also be able to return the nodes with no relationships of the given type.

So far I am just doing the following (I only want the `id` property):

```
MATCH path=(a)-[:KNOWS*]->(b)
RETURN collect(extract(n in nodes(path) | n.id)) as paths
```

I need the paths so that in the programming language (in this case clojure) I can create a nested map like this:

```
{"a" {"b" {"f" {"g" {"k" {"l" {"m" nil}}
                     "h" {"n" nil}}}
           "c" {"d" {"e" nil}
                "i" {"j" nil}}}}}
```

Is it possible to generate the map directly with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one query that will get you started.  This query will return just the longest chain of nodes when there is a single chain without forks. It matches all of the paths like yours does but only returns the longest one by using limit to reduce the result.

```
MATCH p=(a:Node {name:'a'})-[:KNOWS*]->(:Node)
WITH length(p) AS size, p
ORDER BY size DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN p AS Longest_Path
```

I think this gets the second part of your question where there are multiple paths. It looks for paths where the last node does not have an **outbound** `:KNOWS` relationship and where the starting node does not have an **inbound** `:KNOWS` relationship.

```
MATCH p=(a:Node {name:'a'})-[:KNOWS*]->(x:Node)
WHERE NOT x-[:KNOWS]->()
AND NOT ()-[:KNOWS]->(a)
WITH length(p) AS size, p
ORDER BY size DESC
RETURN reduce(node_ids = [], n IN nodes(p) | node_ids + [id(n)])
```

Comment: Without the `limit 1` I get everything I need plus the sub-paths.. There must be a way to filter them out..

Comment: In your first question don't you just want the longest path?

Comment: I may have been unclear. I need all of the paths from root to leaf - including the roots with no children - so that I can use them to build a map in clojure using `assoc-in` (I'm not sure if you're familiar...).

Comment: @merb, i updated the answer for the second part where you have multiple end points. I think it fits the bill. It includes the longest chains and does not return any sub-segments.

Answer (score 2):

Just had to do something similar, this worked on your example, finds all nodes which do not have outgoing `[:KNOWS]`:

```
match p=(a:Node {name:'a'})-[:KNOWS*]->(b:Node)
optional match (b)-[v:KNOWS]->()
with p,v
where v IS NULL
return collect(extract(n in nodes(p) | n.id)) as paths
```